# Centos 7 - ping (connect: Network is unreachable)

Tags: linux, networking, ping, centos-7

I set up a CentOS virtual machine, it is connected to my network, and I tried to ping other machines but nothing worked. Tried to check other machines, they among themselves without problems respond. I would be very grateful for help in finding and understanding the error

etc/resolv.conf

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search local
nameserver 195.46.39.39
nameserver 195.46.39.40
```

etc/sysconfig/network

```
NETWORKING=YES
HOSTNAME=WS-35-18-83
DNS1=195.46.39.39
DNS2=195.46.49.40
```

etc/sysconfigs/network-scripts/ifcfg-enpBs3

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF =yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=enpBs3
UUID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
DEVICE=enpBs3
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=208.35.18.5
NETMASK=255.255.255.240
GATEWAY=208.35.18.15
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

IP on all machines:

1. 208. 35.18.3 (Windows XP)
2. 208. 35.18.4 (Windows 7)
3. 208. 35.18.5 (CentOS)

Network settings on all machines

[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147644/discussion-on-question-by---centos-7-ping-connect-network-is-u); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

**Two mistakes:**

- The first one is wrong NETMASK
- The second - it was necessary to restart all services responsible for
  the network

*Special thanks for your help John and Romeo Ninov*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).